# Passing param to ngOnInit through service

Tags: angular, microservices, micro-frontend

I just started learning about angular 2 and I am having questions on if the scenario I think is possible.

I have a micro service model where in I have angular apps associated to each micro service.

- Microservice 1 & ng app 1 - is for handling the transactions of the
  user
- service 2 and ng app 2 - is to calculate all applicable taxes for the user

If I land on app 1, enter the details of my transaction and click a continue button, I  should be able to pass "All" the values that are required for tax calculation along with the user Id?

Passing it through URL should work but i have user ID, transactionID, transaction amount etc to be bit secure.

Would I be able to pass it through ngOnInit() or through some life cycle event so that ng app 2 gets those details and the page loads with the tax values based on the init params passed? Help me on this :)

Comment: what you meant by ng-app1 and ng-app2 ? is both are two Angular applications side by side or component?

Comment: @NinjaJami It means two angular applications, kind of micro-ui associated to each micro service

Comment: I have added an answer which also help you

Comment: Also I would suggest edit your question title by changing to 'How to communication between two micro front end applications'. It will give more reach to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you seem to have is Microfrontends. Just like each microservice is designed for a very specific entity, each micro frontend is designed for a very specific entity. And that's what you seem to have.

A very common approach of sharing data between micro frontends is by defining custom events.

A micro frontend(A) can emit an event like this:

```
// this is attached to the button in micro-frontend A
btn.onclick = () => {
  const event = new Event("a__click");
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Another micro frontend(B) can listen to that event and react accordingly:

```
// fire this when the micro-frontend initializes
window.addEventListener("a__click", () => this.onUpdateCount());

// actual method to update the count
onUpdateCount(amt = 1) {
  this.state.count += amt;
  const countEl = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("b__count");
  countEl.innerHTML = this.state.count;
}
```

Here's an [**amazingly enlightening article**](https://medium.com/@benjamin.d.johnson/exploring-micro-frontends-87a120b3f71c) on Medium by a guy named Benjamin Johnson that you might want to read to know more about it.

That being said, since these are DOM Events, someone could still intercept them somehow. In those cases, you could have a custom microservice implemented that could return a particular sensitive information and then do the needful with that.

Comment: Completely get it . Thanks for the explanation. But, like in my case 1) do a transaction in app1 , 2) move to app 2 and calculate tax 3)comeback to 1st app and deduct tax and proceed the transaction. Would all of them be custom events ? How would i persist info in app 1 after navigating to app 2 ?

Comment: @Poppy, I guess the info won't be persisted in App 1, it would be persisted in the microservice that App1 consumes. App1 is just going to have some sort of a unique id with the help of which it could get all the relevant details from the microservice.

Comment: Yeah.. Makes sense :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also worked on the same kind of Architecture using [single-spa meta framework](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview.html) . What I did was I have created my own dispatcher utility using plain Javascript(Reusable API) using RxJS , because any way Angular have a dependency of RxJS. So we can take the advantage of it.

Here is the code I have implemented , You can publish and subscribe from any micro front end applications(Angular,React,Vue.js). The code I have written in ts. You can convert to js if you want.

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
(function (global: any) {
  var RxDispatcher: any = function () {
    return new RxDispatcher.instance();
  };
  RxDispatcher.prototype = {
    getDispatcher: function (dispatcherName: string): Subject<any> {
      if (global.subjects) {
        return global.subjects[dispatcherName]
          ? global.subjects[dispatcherName]
          : console.error(
            "Unable to find the dispatcher of " +
            dispatcherName +
            " .Please ensure the dispatchers are properly registered."
          );
      }
      console.error(
        "Unable to find the dispatcher of " +
        dispatcherName +
        " .Please ensure the dispatchers are properly registered."
      );
    },
    registerDispatchers: function (dispatchers: string[]) {

      if (dispatchers) {
        if (!global.subjects) {
          global.subjects = {};
        }
        dispatchers.forEach(dispatcher => {
          if (!global.subjects[dispatcher]) {
            global.subjects[dispatcher] = new Subject();
          }
        });
      }
    },
    dispatch: function (dispatcher: string, args?:any): void {
      if (!dispatcher) {
        console.error(
          "Unable to dispatch message to dispatcher of " + dispatcher
        );
      } else {
        var dispatcherInstance = this.getDispatcher(dispatcher);
        if (dispatcherInstance) dispatcherInstance.next(args);
      }
    },
    dispatchToMultiple: function (dispatchers: string[],args?:any) {
      if (!dispatchers) {
        console.error(
          "Unable to dispatch message to dispatcher of " + dispatchers
        );
      }
      dispatchers.forEach(subscriber => {
        var dispatcherInstance = this.getDispatcher(subscriber);
        if (dispatcherInstance) dispatcherInstance.next(args);
      });
    },
    clear: function () {
      delete global["subjects"];
    }
  };
  RxDispatcher.instance = function () { };
  RxDispatcher.instance.prototype = RxDispatcher.prototype;
  global.RxDispatcher = RxDispatcher;
})(window);
```

**Usage**

if you are in typescript , you have to declare

> declare var RxDispatcher: any;

**Register Dispatchers**

```
 var dispatchers=["onSendMessage"]
 RxDispatcher().registerDispatchers(dispatchers); //expecting an array.
 You can register multiple dispatchers at one time
```

**Send Message**

```
 RxDispatcher().dispatch("onSendMessage", {
       message: "Hi"
    })
```

**Subscribe Message**

```
  RxDispatcher().getDispatcher("onSendMessage")
         .subscribe((message) => {
           console.log(message) //Output : Hi
        });
```